# Compare two php files and remove matching lines

Tags: php, duplicates, include

Ok, so I have two files

```
a.php
b.php
```

I know how to include the file and display content from the php file:

```
<?php include("https://www.example.com/a.php"); ?>
```

The a above code works perfectly.

What I'm getting problem with, is when I'm trying to compare two php files and remove matches.

I have this code, but it doesn't output anything. A blank.

```
<?php
$lines1 = include("https://www.example.com/a.php");
$lines2 = include("https://www.example.com/b.php");
$result = array_diff( $lines1, $lines2 );
print_r( $result );
?>
```

I have tried this:

```
<?php
$lines1 = include("https://www.example.com/a.php");
echo $lines1;
?>
```

Even the above code doesn't work.

**EDIT:**

Below code did worked (when removed https://www.example.com/):

```
<?php
$lines1 = include("a.php");
echo $lines1;
?>
```

Both php files doesn't include arrays.

Basically both return a list of urls in a new line, like this:

http://www.example.com/1

http://www.example.com/2

Which I want to compare and do not display matched lines.

So, let's say a.php has:

apple

orange

banana

and b.php has:

orange

banana

Then only apple will be displayed. Ignoring the matches.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `array_diff()` only works on arrays. Does your files return arrays? It's kind of impossible for us to know where it goes wrong or how you should do it if we have no clue what the data looks like. To be able to store the contents of `include` in a variable, you either need to return the contents in your files or start output buffering (ob_start()) before including the files and then get the contents from the buffer.

Comment: I figured. No it doesn't return arrays. I have updated the question.

Comment: If you just have a list of URL's, then you should use `file()` instead. That will read the file and return the contents as an array with each line as an array element. Change that and  `var_dump()` the variables to see that they contain what you expect and take it from there.

Comment: Doesn't `file()` work for .txt only?  Just to make clear. My php files doesn't contain plain text lines, they actually execute and then echo the result, which I want then to compare.

Comment: `file()` works with any file type. Either way, PHP files are just text files with a different file extension anyway. And tbh, I don't see the purpose of having them as PHP files if they just contains a list if URL's.

Comment: So you want the unique list of lines from two files? Just de-duplication? Or do you need to only know which lines only appear on one or the other, ignoring matches?

Comment: Basically if the two files contain the same line, it will be ignored and won't display. But iIf one file has a line that the other file doesn't, it will display.

Comment: I have updated my question, hope it makes sense now.

Comment: Are your a.php and b.php actually PHP files, or just text files? If they're PHP files, are you trying to compare the code in them, or the output generated by running that code?

Comment: @M.Eriksson This question is too Unclear to leave open, correct?

Answer (score 0):

The [include](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) function actually imports the PHP code in the included file, so it becomes part of the code in your file, and is evaluated (run) by the PHP interpreter. Looks like you want to use the [file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) function, which reads the lines of a file into an array.

As @AbraCadaver mentioned, if you're including from a URL, you're going to need allow_url_fopen enabled. If you can't do that, you're going to need to use curl or some other HTTP client.

You then need a way to get the distinct entries from both arrays. [array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) does not actually do this, it only returns the entries in the first param that are not present in any of the others. That's not the requirement, and there's no built in (I don't think so anyway) that does this, so let's roll our own.

```php
<?php

$aFile = file('a.txt');
$bFile = file('b.txt');

/**
 * Return the entries that appear in either array, but not both
 * 
 * @param array $a
 * @param array $b
 * @return array
 */
function array_distinct(array $a, array $b)
{
    // Normalize line endings, etc
    $a = array_map('trim', $a);
    $b = array_map('trim', $b);

    // De-dup
    $a = array_unique($a);
    $b = array_unique($b);

    // Get the common items
    $common = array_intersect($a, $b);

    // Merge both arrays
    $all = array_merge($a, $b);

    // Filter out the common entries
    $output = array_diff($all, $common);

    // Re-key on the way out
    return array_values($output);
}

$distinctEntries = array_distinct($aFile, $bFile);

assert(sizeof($distinctEntries)==2, 'We should see two entries');
assert($distinctEntries[0] == 'http://www.example.com/3', 'Entry should match expectation');
assert($distinctEntries[1] == 'http://www.example.com/4', 'Entry should match expectation');

print_r($distinctEntries);
```

a.txt:

```
http://www.example.com/1
http://www.example.com/2
http://www.example.com/3
```

b.txt:

```
http://www.example.com/1
http://www.example.com/2
http://www.example.com/4
http://www.example.com/4
```

Comment: Hey Rob, thanks for the answer. I have tried `file` and `file_get_contents`. Both doesn't work. The only way I managed to display my php file content is with `include`. So I thought it would work for comparing two files, but it doesn't for some reason.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't work like that. See my updated answer.

Comment: update, pasted your code. It outputed this: Array ( [0] => [1] => 'meta_compare' => '!=', [2] => )

Comment: What is the actual content that you're comparing? This code compares lines in files - that's it. Looks like you need more than that. I think you need to start over and review your basic assumptions.

Comment: ok, thanks Rob. Appreciate your time and effort in trying to help. I thought it would be easier, but I was wrong apparently. As as I said previously, those are php files, not plain text lines in a .txt. Those two php files execute this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68307979/wordpress-comparing-two-arrays-and-removing-matches?noredirect=1

Comment: OK, this is completely the wrong approach, you're making a Rube Goldberg machine.

Comment: :DDDDD Not arguing.